# Why are print and printf not printing anything until I've input something?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, printf

I want to print out a prompt on the same line as I'm asking for input, but when I execute this code in intellij it only prints the prompt after something has been input.

- I've tried adding a '%n' to the end of the first printf which worked, but that doesn't do what I want as I want the input to be on the same line.
- I've also tried using System.out.flush() after the first printf but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Input something: ");
        System.out.flush();
        String str = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("You input: %s\n", str);
    }
}
```

I expect the printf("Input something: ") to be printed on the same line as I input on, like so (from Notepad++):

[image]

But when I run the same code in intellij this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: what version of Intelij are you using? Because when I run the same code, (even without the .flush()) it outputs the same result as in your notepad++ version...

Comment: The code works for me.  I’m using an online compiler JDK 10.0.1.

Comment: Use `Console.readLine("prompt")`.

Comment: @el-aasi I'm using the latest version of Intellij community edition.

Comment: Do you use Gradle to run the code? It looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184090 Switch to an [**Application** run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html) (you might want to disabled the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option for this).

Comment: @Andrey Thank you! Disabling "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle" seems to have fixed things.